# How to add $_POST['variable'] to URL of next page?

Tags: php

I have a simple landing page with a search bar and submit button.

I want the URL of the next page to read: `mysite.com/after_search.php?search=*the search text here*`.

Here is the code from the landing page / *index.php* page:

```
  <form class="" action="after_search.php?search="<?php echo $_POST['search_title']?> method="post">
    <div class="form-group" id="search_wrapper">
      <input type="text" id="search_field" class="form-control color-outline" name="search_title" placeholder="Search">
```

The issue is that *$_POST['search_title']* is not set until the next page loads. So, it does not work because *$_POST['search_title']* is not defined on this page.

How do I add the contents of the search bar to the URL of the next page?

**EDIT 1**

It was suggested that I switch to GET instead of POST.

But on the 2nd page, there are many places that use $_POST['...']

Switching all those to $_GET['...'] has allowed it to work.

Thanks, all

Comment: for search use get method  instead of post

Comment: why don't you use `<form methdo='get'>`

Comment: Yea, you guys are right

Comment: If you are not sure whether to use GET or POST, you can use `$_REQUEST`, this works for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$_GET` method to get the values from a URL:

```
<form class="" action="after_search.php" method="get">
```

To get the value, use:

```
$_GET['search']
```

---

If you are passing the value through the link:

```
?search=the search text here
```

That means you are using `$_GET`, thus you need to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting data, so use `GET` method and you want adding the variable in url `GET` method do this.

```
 <form class="" action="after_search.php" method="get">
  <div class="form-group" id="search_wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="search_field" class="form-control color-outline" name="search" placeholder="Search">
```

Comment: In the next page I use $_POST['...'] alot. Should changing to $_GET['...'] work?

Comment: is in this form only a single field ? @Rorschach

Answer (score 1):

If you have this `search_title` in URL you can use `$_GET['search_title']`. If not its unavailable then use a default. Something like

```
action="after_search.php?search=<?php echo isset($_POST['search_title'])? $_POST['search_title']: ''?>"
```

Here I used an empty string () as default.